# django shortcut redirect function redirects from https to http

Tags: django, redirect, https

My site is a facebook app also listening to port 443, so when a user goes to https://mysite.co.nz/entry, there is a redirect function to redirect the user back to home page

```
redirect('thankyou')
```

The problem is, it redirects the user to http://mysite.co.nz/thankyou instead of https, and facebook doesn't like it.

Is this a bug or something? I have seen work arounds by adding redirects to nginx config, but it seems a hack to me.

Comment: This should help you: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12043

Comment: I have been through that page already

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sort of work around since I cannot find a desired solution:

in Nginx:

```
location @django {
  include uwsgi_params;
  uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/site.sock;
  uwsgi_param HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL https;
  uwsgi_param UWSGI_SCHEME   $scheme;
}
```

In django settings:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
```